# Grant "pre-approval" issue

Tags: funding, policy

**Background:** 
I work in a public university as a staff member, and also a part-time lecturer, allowed to teach only 1 class (per Union). 
Last year, I applied and received multiple grants/awards for my teaching position. I already completed the work and received payments. The grants did not require any approvals from department/dean.

**Recent development:** Now, our dean approached me with the following conversation:

“You need to send me info prior to your grant submission.. 
You are only a lecturer…
We hired you just to teach 1 course… 
You have a limit for a course teaching… you have a limit (per Union)...
You need to consult with the dean and the department chair about any grant’s proposal and share your idea with us…
 I know that you are not required to submit for internal review to the dean, but since I knew nothing about it, I was in a dark, moving forward you must inform me about your plans… You need to work with a tenured faculty on grants…”

**My question:** 
What do I suppose to do in this situation? I obviously do not believe dean’s well wishes, and would like to apply grants in the future without “dean’s blessings”. I also feel that the dean would go behind my back and ask for denial of my proposal. I do not wish to share my ideas for free.

Comment: Why not finding an tenured ally in the faculty and work with them? That would make it harder for the dean to sabotage your proposal (if that is indeed what you fear).

Comment: Tenured ally  are absolutely not interested to do extra work. And I rather do everything by myself.

Comment: It's not about my trust in administration. My intellectual property does not belong to the admin.

Comment: @CP I don't see how the admin is claiming your IP. Sending an email to the dean would provide a paper trail that it is your IP. If you want to get into IP discussions though you will have to consult a lawyer, since the university may be able to claim any IP related to your work anyway.

Comment: If I shared my ideas for the grants, I believe I would not be a recipient of any grant. The deans statements are directing me to stop applying for the grants. I believe the dean has no authority here, it's out of the scope.

Comment: @CP I'm not sure what country you are in, but I would interpret the dean as being your boss's boss and would have complete authority over this, especially if the grants have *any* relationship to your university position. You should definitely bring this up with your department chair to clarify.

Comment: Ideally, yes. Reality, the department chair does not care about it.

Comment: In the US, it's fairly normal to require approval of grant proposals by the administration before they are submitted.  You haven't specified what country you are in or who you submitted these proposals to but in the case of major federal funding agencies in the US such as the NSF, grants are awarded to the university rather than to individual faculty and staff members.

Comment: Once again, my grants did not require dean's approval. It was approved by a special university committee. I am in the US.

Comment: Why don't you want to just get the dean's approval? I don't see any reason they would say no, it sounds like they're just annoyed there's `N` dollars in their department now that they didn't budget for.

Comment: Of course, if you take *this* attitude, you might get a "no."

Comment: Incorrect. The additional budget comes to the department for the grant with my name.

Comment: I think I clearly stated that I do not wish to share my ideas prior grant submission with anyone. And I do not believe dean's well wishes.

Comment: "I was in a dark"  No manager wants to be surprised by something going on in their organization.

Comment: It is not unheard of for software companies in the US to, in their contracts, lay claim to anything their employees create while an employee. What makes you think that while being paid by a university, your ideas should be hidden from it, and that if your employer asks you to share your ideas, that they are in the wrong?

Comment: @CP If your "Incorrect" comment was directed at me, I don't see how that's right, when you followed it up with saying "the additional budget comes to the department ..." which is exactly what I just said.

Comment: @CP Again, if your second comment is also directed at me, you need to explain why you are so damn protective of your teaching ideas. That is not normal academic behavior, and we are all very confused by what you think is going to happen if you just get the dean to rubber-stamp your proposal.

Comment: @CP Not "all" of us are confused. Majority doesn't mean "right". I see your point. Hopefully you will find the best way, and update here on how things came out.

Comment: @Scientist, thanks again. A lot of politically correct responses were given, and someone below even got into embezzlement.  I lost desire to respond.

Comment: @CP I think this community is biased towards defenders of institutional establishment. I have seen it in several other threads about e.g. student vs. professor conflicts, advisor vs. advisee. Perhaps posting here what looks good to department fellas. Anyways, perhaps I am in the wrong, or just out of tune with local practices somewhere. I believe you've seen different views, and this is what counts.

Comment: @Scientist There are very nasty bureaucrats around, no question. But nothing in the question of OP suggests evidence for that. There is just the position that OP doesn't want to share ideas, without further explanation. "It's mine!" is a comfortable position when you will be indulged or can afford it, i.e. a little kid, or a very powerful businessperson, but in most contexts life is a compromise of give and take. Unless therefore OP has evidence of being scammed out of ideas, this should at least be considered. It's not PC, it's simply practical. If OP believes that they can go against...

Comment: ... the dean, then why do they ask the question here, to random strangers on the internet who know neither OP nor the dean? Either OP are formally allowed to go against the dean (because the committee is independent and the grant not under control of the dean) or not. In which case, the dean cannot stop the grant, but sabotage OP in other forms, including continued employment. Again, this is not PC, but simply reality. It has nothing to do with defending institutions. Gravity, like institutional bureaucracy, sucks, whether it's being defended or not. OP can ignore this, at their own peril.

Comment: @CP: it seems that your edit essentially erased the whole question.  Whether intentional or not, this isn't allowed, so I reversed it.  If there is information you need to add or clarify, you can use an edit to do that, but you can't delete the whole thing.

Answer (score 22):

It might help to understand where your Dean is coming from. I work for my university's research administration department, and I can understand his position. For context, we are an R1 university in the United States.

There are likely a few things going on:

1. Grants often create liabilities for universities. There may be cost-sharing requirements or other implicit costs which the university will be required to pay. Administrators need to keep a close eye on these requirements in order to keep the university functioning smoothly.
2. Grants create risks for universities. There are many legal and ethical rules surrounding grants. Although some of the risk is on you, much of the potential penalties are assumed by the university. For this reason, many (if not all) research universities have dedicated research administration departments and all grants are required to flow through those departments.
3. There are legal issues. In all of the grants I've seen, the grant goes from the granting agency to your employer. It is not a grant to you personally. You should be careful about accepting money on your own. Carefully re-read the grant terms to be sure that this is not the case here.
4. Not all the reasons are bad: universities often like to reward individuals and departments who do a great job of soliciting grant dollars. If they can't keep an eye on grants, how are they supposed to that?

Other answers have mentioned intellectual property. I'll only repeat what they have said: if you work for a university you should not assume that any intellectual work product is your own property. Make sure you understand what the rules are in your location.

Overall, I would treat this as an opportunity to develop in your profession. If soliciting grants is an important part of your career (current or future!) then it would help to understand how it works. It's not as simple as just applying for a grant - and for good reason!

Comment: My points and more good ones. (+1)

Comment: I would add one point to this. The dean has some responsibility to know what is going on among lecturers they are supervising. Having grant money appear without prior knowledge would make the dean look inefficient.

Comment: What also may be consideration - when does one work on the grants? Since they are related to the perk of job (the 1 course) one could rationalize that OP's time on job should/could be used in researching grants available, writing the grants. But, then what does this take away from other staff responsibilities and is it worth the effort for the course being taught? Wouldn't that be a normal discussion between admin staff and their immediate manager (Dean?) before getting too involved?  (I would have expected teaching a course would have taken up almost all extra flexible time!)

Comment: #4 (providing rewards) is unconvincing as a reason here. If the administration lets it be known that they will reward grant winners, then people will automatically be motivated to inform the administration after they get one. #1-3 are reasons to prohibit cowboy grant-writing; #4 is not.

Comment: I agree that is unlikely to be the answer to OP's problem, but I am leaving it in because other readers may find it informative.

Answer (score 18):

If you aren't willing to do what upper administration is directly telling you to do, then either:

- Be willing to accept the consequences when you go against the dean.
- Look for a new university with administration that you can trust.

To summarize my responses to you in the comments:

- You seem worried about your intellectual property. However, the university may already own this. You'll have to check your university policies and talk to a lawyer. If you document your ideas (e.g., an email to the dean with your grant proposal draft) then you would be able to show that you authored it.
- You seem to think the dean has an ill intent. However, you haven't provided any evidence of this. From what you have said, it seems like the dean just wants to know what is going on and possibly protect the university and or you from liability issues caused by the grants (e.g., it is outside your job description, you claimed your university affiliation when applying for the grant, you are using university resources for grant work without approval).

In other words, if you are receiving grant money (or doing anything) in what appears to be an official capacity of your work position (lecturer at a university), then the university has a right to know about it (and to prevent you from doing it).

Comment: It does not make sense. The dean has no right to make me share my intellectual property without my agreement.

Comment: @CP There is nothing in your question about IP. Can you clarify the original question?

Comment: Since you work for the university, the IP situation is complicated anyway; especially if the grants you request are supported by your affiliation with the university. If you have a reason to distrust your admins, and no support from the other faculty, you really have no chance but to change to a more congenial environment. In our department, you cannot even submit proposals for grants without getting signatures from at least 3 levels of admin.

Comment: I had some teaching ideas, applied for the grant, implemented them, got payments, the dean did not like that.

Comment: The grants only needed my proposals. No other approvals.

Comment: You were talking about IP. Please clarify. In the meantime, Austin's response is pertinent.

Comment: My proposals are IPs and the extra work I did for it to implement the proposals. It was my extra work designed for the grants. Not sure what else to add.

Comment: Still unclear: it may not be your (or your complete) IP if you did that work when paid by the university. This is a different issue from whether you want to prevent your dean from stopping you submitting or whether you do not wish to share ideas with your colleagues but rather make sure only you get the credit. Three different questions. Which of these is your goal?

Comment: My goals: 1 Get paid. 2. I am not obligated to share any ideas if I do not want to. 3. Get more grants.

Comment: @CP Goals #1 and #2 might contradict each other.

Comment: The IP is mine, since I created the idea. The result of the idea (implemented product) does belong to the university since yes I got paid for it to implement it.

Comment: If I share the idea(#2), I will not get paid(#1). Yes, they do contradict, I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: IP is a legal term. So, you may not own it if you work for the uni. It's different from authorship.

Comment: The idea is nothing then? In my case, I call my ideas - IPs, since I see someone's trying to steal it. I do believe the university does not own my ideas. I am in US.

Comment: I did not say that the idea is nothing. But IP is a legal term. It's not for you to decide how that is interpreted, there is a precise legal framework for that - especially as lots of money may be involved with it. If you can apply without asking the dean, it's one thing. Which consequence this will have for your status in the department is another. Also, it is not typical that grant money can go directly to an individual, but if in your case it is possible, that's good news for you.

Comment: @CP: In every other job in the world, you have a responsibility to keep your bosses informed about the work you are doing, in as much detail as they request.  Academic jobs are no different.

Comment: @CP  "I had some teaching ideas, applied for the grant, implemented them,got payments..." There are two possible issues with this: 1) The dean may not like you do experiments with teaching a class. It is hard to elaborate more without knowing what exactly you implemented, but there are many teaching innovations which require approval before being implemented... 2) You got hired by the Uni to teach a class, and then you received money from other sources to make changes to that class. That could be problematic...

Answer (score 12):

Technically speaking, many grants are made to the university and not to
the applicant personally. University grants offices are typically paid a small
percentage of the grant amount for administering the grant and in many
cases a larger percentage of the grant amount for 'indirect costs' (library
usage, computer facilities, etc.).

For such grants it is usually a requirement
for deans and university grants officers to approve the application.
I am not saying your dean is a 'nice guy'. Or that union contracts make any logical sense. I'm just saying make sure
you know the rules of the granting agency and the university before you
make grant applications.

Answer (score 7):

You are using the department's resources (that includes *your* working time) to work on your grant projects. To do that without the departments knowledge is close to embezzlement. This dean is actually *very nice to you* at the moment.

He has every right to know *before* what you're applying for, and what you need for it. Desk space for a student, your working time, equipment, lab time, lab space, etc. The scientific details of your project are possibly of no concern to him, but unless you are hired as an independent researcher, he still has every *right* to demand that you share them. Because you are already using department resources to *write* the proposals.

Answer (score 3):

It is not likely that the dean is out to get you (he probably has better things to do). Follow his advice and see what happens (he will have some expertise that you don't at this time). You are likely young and whatever happens is not going to have any lasting effects on you.

On the other hand you may discover that the dean is a nice person and make a friend.

In the worst case scenario, you will find that the dean's advice should not be followed and have a 'reason' to go back to your 'old ways'.

Answer (score -8):

I believe you're in a tight situation. But do not feel singled out: I have heard of many such cases where department higher ranks exploit younger staff. The academia is unfortunately full of opportunistic predators nowadays. This person seeks to be put in a position from where he can blackmail and manipulate you.

I do not know anything of the local social & cultural standards of where you are, or whether you are a local, or an immigrant. I am afraid you must make a moral choice which will affect your personal life and career. This person probably seeks to parasitise and sabotage you. You must find a way of neutralising his actions with minimal damage.

The best for everyone else in the bigger picture is that you confront this dean head on. Offering open resistance and wide exposure directly weakens a bad workmate. If everyone resists, abusers cannot thrive. Problem is, it will likely cost you your peace at work, and force you to move away. Possibly confronting authorities may not be socially acceptable (e.g. China) adding to a bad reputation and extra enemies / penalties.

Another way is to scam the abuser. You may pretend to scared and frame fake ideas and proposals, provide elusive information. This will lead to a cold war and eventually he will realise, but it buys you time (e.g. a dean may be temporary).

Or you simply abide and pray for the best. This is probably what this person is used to seeing.

Evaluate your chances where you are, and whether moving on to a better environment wouldn't be the best for you. By all means, when you get the chance, please do neutralise this person. Time is your friend against abusers.

Good luck.

Comment: I have always resisted abuse, ever since school. I think it pays off but it is frequently uncomfortable.

Comment: I am now trying to find a way to resist in a smart way. It's hard. It's just killing me.

Comment: `This person probably seeks to parasitise and sabotage you` Where is this coming from?? Other than the OP's feeling, there seems to be no evidence of this. I interpreted the dean's request as being inline with their duties.

Comment: All the statements from the dean are saying "do not get grants". If you attempt to get them, send them to the dean. This is just a dead end game.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a parasitic move then. He may be trying to protect you and or the university. For example, since it is outside of your job description the grants might lead to liability issues for the university (are you listing your university affiliation when applying for them?) or they are using the universities resources without being approved.

Comment: @AustinHenley Yes, I read your answer. I read the move in a different way. Also I do not think the dean has a duty to control grant applications from everyone (what to say from specific targets).

Comment: @CP It is hard because you probably don't like playing games. Passive-aggressive, lying, faking smiles, scamming, implied threats, etc. It tends to become quite unhealthy. If you find out how to neutralise this person, it may end quicker.

Comment: I am curios how would you "neutralize this person"?

Comment: @AustinHenley I see you are a good person, with a good heart. This is probably way you do not see the hidden damage this negative person did. My husband is kinda like you. It must be really dark for him to see the damage.

Comment: @CP This is totally context-specific. Bad academics often publish obvious misconduct (e.g. in verbatim plagiarism or image manipulation), others heavily rely on a facade reputation or a specific collaboration, or even pinpoint protection. Some are actually desperate thus some resistance would suffice to cut them off (e.g. tenure or main funding is on a deadline). It is hard to say, one needs to study their enemies. This is why I tend to recommend just fighting openly and moving elsewhere -- it is easier and way healthier.

Comment: @Scientist I feel that I need to apply for another grant and see what this person does next.

Comment: It is not likely that the dean is out to get you. Follow his advice and see what happens. You are likely young and whatever happens is not going to have any lasting effect. You may discover that the dean is a nice person and make a friend.

Comment: @CP I was wondering whether you found a solution? Please also mind to select the most helpful answer for you in this thread. It would be interesting if it proves to have been this one. So many users here strive to maintain the current status quo of institutional oppression.

Comment: @Scientist Thank you for asking. For now, there is no new grant opportunity, so I am not applying at this time. I am also looking into non-job related opportunities where I can get a better level of satisfaction.